# Texlive 2014 in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, latex, texlive

Okay,

So I have 14.04 with texlive installed by default. I'm trying to install texlive packages but whenever I try, for instance running `sudo tlmgr install multirow` I get the message that the repository doesn't support my version (2013). However when I run `tlmgr --version` it tells me I am `using installation /usr/local/texlive/2014` and running `TeX Live (<http address>) version 2014`.

I've tried to install texlive 2014 version from the texlive site using their instructions, and I can even find it installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2014`. I just don't know how to get the darned thing working.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the packaged TL2013

The texlive version that goes along with 14.04 is 2013:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-base

As the texlive development progresses, old data is made available using the historic repositories. If you want to stick with TL2013, you need to change the repository to the correct value like this:

`tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/tlnet-final`

#### Use the manually installed TL2014

To get a sane environment where things are no longer mixed up, first uninstall TL2013: `apt-get purge texlive-base`, then re-install TL2014. If questions arise, you can either post them here, or on tex.se

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use this if necessary, but I am looking to be using the 2014 version if possible, of go no other reason than to give me a better understanding of Linux.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that when I get back to my machine and report back.

Comment: Okay with a combination of this and a lot of dicking about with setting paths correctly I finally have it working properly... I think.